# How to add jar Library to jEdit?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, jedit

I want to add SwingSets3(BeautyEyeLNFDemo).jar to my program library in jEdit.

I can do this easily in netbeans, by using add jar/folder on library folder.

[image: Netbeans add jar]

I try moving the .jar file to program folder and Jedit folder but it doenst work.

I have instaled some of jEdit Plugin, those are :

```
Antelope
Astyle Beautifier
Beauty
BufferTabs
Console
Editor Scheme
Error List
First Mate
Info Viewer
Jakarta Commons
Javadoc
JavaFold
Java SideKick
JSwat Plugin
Maven
Project Viewer
Project Wizard
Sidekick
TextAutoComplete
```

Comment: I don't think jEdit out-of-the-box integrates with a compiler toolchain. It's not an IDE, "just" a text editor. Are you using a plugin for Java development?

Comment: yes, i use many java-centric plugins, including here http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073597/developer-tools-ide/power-java-programming--8212-free-.html

Comment: How this has to be done depends on the plugins you use. Maybe you should review the documentation of the plugins you are using. If you expect help here, you should probably at least list the plugins you are using.

Comment: @Vampire waw, jEdit dev here :), i want to thank you so much to you Sir, i sent you an email long time ago. thank you so much sir, thank you.

Comment: yw :-) ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right click your project in `ProjectViewer`, select `Properties`, then `Classpath` and `Add Element ...`, then you add your library JAR and you're done.

Comment: thanks lot Sir, it solve my problem. ( but i have to exract the jar files to the classpath) . it solved thanks : )  [this](http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a209/azzamsa/stackoverflow_3%20-%20jedit%20-%20SOLVED_zpszffkehzw.png) is the result. hope one day, I can give benefit to community as like you.

Comment: you're welcome. I don't think you need to extract the JARs, does not make much sense, but should work too. But whatever works for you is fine. :-)

Comment: how does this integrate with gradle?

Comment: What is "this" and what has it to do with this question? If you ask whether ProjectViewer integrates with Gradle, not that I know of.