# how to handle imports with jEdit?

Tags: java, plugins, import, ide, jedit

Having some [problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/947304/45156) with Netbeans; not able to [login](https://www.drupal.org/node/2902838) to the jEdit forum.  Is there some plugin to configure which will handle auto-imports as Netbeans does with `ctrl-shift-i`?  (Probably I'll just try Eclipse, but would like to try jEdit.)

see also:

[How to add jar Library to jEdit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39736002/262852)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points:

- it is jEdit, not JEdit
- distributed login on the community page does not work, as the SourceForge servers do not support outbound network traffic, so you need an account on the comunity page to login
- looking through http://plugins.jedit.org, [LazyImporter](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?LazyImporter) seems to be what you are after
- jEdit is in my opinion one of the best and most flexible text editors, but that is all it ever really aimed to be. A programmers text editor with integrated syntax highlighting for many languages, but it is no IDE. You can add many IDE-like functionality by plugins that are available and thus configure your jEdit to be a suitable IDE for small projects. If you are not happy with jEdit as IDE, I'd strongly recommend IntelliJ IDEA. It is simply the best Java IDE under the sun, Netbeans and Eclipse are really PITA compared with it. I even use IntelliJ IDEA to develop jEdit. :-)

Comment: "so you need an account on the community page.." which community does that mean?  SourceForge?  Or anyone?  Because I have the Drupal account for their forums.  Just curious, kinda want to know at this point.

Comment: I understood that you cannot login to community.jedit.org with your drupal account. This is true, it technically does not work. You need an account on community.jedit.org to log in. This is totally independent from a SourceForge account.